# dotnet installed but computer doesn't seem to see it

Tags: .net-core

I've installed `Microsoft .NET Core SDK 3.1.201 (x64)`. It can be seen in my Programs and Features but when I enter the `dotnet --version` into the cmd I get:

```
'dotnet' is not recognised as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Is there anything I need to do to get it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `dotnet` binary location to system path. In your case (Windows) check if the default location for this binary is not included in PATH and if not, then include it.

```
setx path "%path%;C:\Program Files\dotnet"
```